# What is the best practice to send data to layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering what is the best way to efficiently send data from controller to layout. Normally, I use the layout with yield directive to render the page. So this is my layout

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%= yield(:title) %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the view file

```
<% content_for :title do %>
    <title><%= @title %></title>
<% end %>

<section id="page-body">
   <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
</section>
```

With this approach, I have to define the @title instance variable in my controller in every method where the @title data is required in its view.

The real problem is that my title and other meta data are stored in the database and because the view uses the same layout file. So I think these data like title and keywords should not be loaded too frequently (At least, not in every method) and content_for should not be declared in every view.

So is there any way for the layout to access these data from the controller directly? without using content_for

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Set the value in `ApplicationController`
2. Set "default" values at init

---

**Controller**

If you're [subclassing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses) your controllers from `ApplicationController`, `ApplicationController` is always being called. This means that if you want/need to set values from your DB, you can do it with a `before_action` callback:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_meta

  private

  def set_meta
    @title ||= ...
  end
end
```

You'd then populate your layout as follows:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<title><%= @title || "Fallback" %></title>
```

--

**Defaults**

If you have site-wide data you wish to populate your `layout` with, you'll be best setting `defaults` / `constants` with an initializer:

```
#config/initializers/meta.rb
META = {
  title:    Option.find_by name: "title"
  keywords: Option.find_by name: "keywords"
}
```

We've used one of the ["config"](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) gems to populate this data:

```
#config/settings.yml
site:
  title:    <%= Option.find_by name: "title" %>
  keywords: <%= Option.find_by name: "keywords" %>

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<title><%= yield(:title) || Settings.title %></title>
```